# JavaFx - how to make zoom in/out with mouse wheel?

Tags: javafx

I have a `ScrollPane` and I would like to zoom In/Out with a mouse wheel event.

The furthest I got is the code below. My problem is that there is no way to know the direction as `e.getDeltaY()` always returns 0.0.

```
ScrollPane scroll = new ScrollPane(stack);
scroll.setFitToWidth(true);
scroll.setFitToHeight(true);

scroll.setOnScroll(e -> {
    if (e.isControlDown()) {
        System.out.println(e.getDeltaY());
        System.out.println(e.getTotalDeltaY());
        e.consume();
    }
});
```

How can I implement mouse wheel + ctrl to zoom in / out ?

Using JavaFX 14 ea on Linux Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: worksforme (fx11)

Comment: ops, I meant 14 ea. It has some bug fixes that I need.

Comment: Are you getting an event and the `deltaY` is `0` or are you not even receiving an event?

Comment: deltaY always zero.